# React Native, scrolling TextInput behind a ToolbarAndroid

Tags: reactjs, scrollview, react-native, native, textinput

I've been stuck on the following issue for awhile now.  I have a ToolbarAndroid component and a TextInput component:

```
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ToolbarAndroid
      navIcon={require('./ic_menu_black_24dp.png')}
      onIconClicked={() => this.drawer.openDrawer()}
      style={styles.titleView}
      title="Blah"
      titleColor="black"
    />

    <ScrollView>
          <TextInput
          {...this.props}
          multiline={true}
          onChange={(event) => {
            this.setState({
              text: event.nativeEvent.text,
              height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
              color: 'black'
            });
          }}
          style={{fontSize: 14, textAlignVertical: 'top', height: Math.max(60, this.state.height)}}
          value={this.state.text}
          placeholder="Spread your message!"
          placeholderTextColor='lightslategray'
          underlineColorAndroid='white'
          enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
          returnKeyType="done"
          maxLength={1000}
        />
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

My TextInput box is auto-expanding which means it grows as it types.  The input also re-focuses on top of the keyboard as it grows.  However, as it grows to be bigger than my screen, it doesn't scroll behind the Toolbar.  Instead, it pushes the toolbar off the screen.  I'd like it to scroll behind the toolbar but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If possible, can you please recreate this example on [RNPlay](https://rnplay.org/)? That would make it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Here it is: https://rnplay.org/apps/y9siAA

Just click on the text box, and keep pressing Enter for a newline.  I want the text contents to scroll behind the green toolbar but it doesn't.  Instead it scrolls the toolbar up out of the view.

Comment: I made some [changes](https://rnplay.org/apps/0HF9pg) to your code. But the problem persists. In fact, this is how it should work. It is primarily because of the keyboard. When you focus on a `TextInput`, which is out of visible view, android automatically adjusts the `View` and contents of the `View` to show cursor above the keyboard i.e. the cursor should always be visible to the user. For that, even `ToolbarAndroid` is shifted out of the visible boundary. IMO, there is no work-around for this.

Comment: It's weird, in the UIExplorer Demo provided as part of the React Native Examples, they seem to be able to do that properly.  Under the TextInput Example, they have an auto-expanding form which slides "behind" the toolbar.  I can't seem to replicate that functionality though.